# Why does Javascript file get empty array from php file? Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am creating the plugin that calculates income taxes. I don't need to reload page so I am going to use ajax. I need to get a plugin's path and transfer it to javascript file.

```
$my_data_array = [];

add_shortcode('penalty', 'penalty_calculator');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_scripts' );

function my_styles_scripts(){
    global $my_data_array;

    wp_register_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( 'js/my_functions.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js' );

    wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'dataObj', $my_data_array );
}



function penalty_calculator(){
    global $my_data_array;

    $my_data_array= [
        'path' => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)
    ];


    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" class="income_tax_calculator">

        <?php wp_nonce_field(); ?>

        <p>
            <label for="income_tax">How many charges are there?</label>
            <input type="text" name="income_tax" id="income_tax">
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="calculate_income_tax" id="calculate_income_tax" value="Calculate">
        </p>

    </form>

    <?php

}
```

my js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    console.log(dataObj)   // empty!

    $("#calculate_income_tax").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var income_tax = $("#income_tax").val();

        // ajax, post, calculate.php is in plugin directory

    });

});
```

My javascript file get empty dataObj array from php file and I don't know why. I load my javascript file after jQuery, in the footer, but array is till empty. Javascript file is really found in the footer in view source code.

Generally, am I in a good way? This is my first plugin.

Comment: It's probably not copied right, but you have error in js. You need one more '})' in the end

Comment: Yes, I didin't copied right. I fixed this in the question. JS doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: I cant see any place in the code you have provided that you declare dataObj..  are we missing something?

Comment: there is: wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'dataObj', $my_data_array ); As I understand this should transfer data to my js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_styles_scripts' );
```

not

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_scripts' );
```